# UITextView automatic scroll down

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have an `UIView` and I add a editable `UITextView` to it,

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 219, 47)];
[self addSubview:textView];
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

When I type it doesn't go down automatic. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if found a solution

i put the textview into a view and set the view to clipToBounds = YES
then i put the textView to a height of 70

that fixed the problem.

very strange solution, but it finally works :)

Comment: If 70 is lower than your UITextView's original height then it gets clipped to that value an probably by coincidence this is exactly what it takes for your case to "autoscroll" to the last line. It's a little too hackish :)

Answer (score 52):

Just figured out that you must use a length > 0. Ie

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 1);
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
```

Worked for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. You also need to check if textView.text.length > 0.

Comment: Note that this will cause the textView to scroll to the bottom. It's not a great idea to put this in UITextView's textViewDidChange: delegate; if you are editing at the top of the textview, it'll get scrolled to the bottom, which is not what the user would expect.

Comment: tried different solutions but this is the one worked like a charm

Comment: @ZS I met this issue when using this code. Is there any way to get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259886/uitextview-cursor-not-positioning-properly-when-editing-in-ios-7-why/19298022#19298022

Answer (score 11):

To scroll to the end of the buffer I tried

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length]-1, 1)];
```

But nothing happened.
Instead this works

```
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you'll have to do

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:[textView selectedRange]];
```

in `textDidChange`.

Comment: hmm, strange. can you try [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(textView.text.length, 0)];

Answer (score 5):

When adding text to a text box programmatically, I found I also needed to add "[textView layoutIfNeeded]" to set things up before the new scroll position could be calculated correctly.

for example:

```
[newString appendFormat:@"%@\n",addText];
textView.text = newString;
[textView layoutIfNeeded];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 2, 1); //I ignore the final carriage return, to avoid a blank line at the bottom
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range]
```

Without this addition the textbox would sometimes not scroll, or would scroll several lines every time a single line of data was added.

Comment: This worked for me:

`[textView layoutIfNeeded];
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2. It works for me

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

   let bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height)
   textView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It seems to work when the UITextView is larger than its content, but as soon as the content grows larger than the size on the screen, it's no longer scrolling for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the text added to the UITextView contained carriage returns, then the textview would not scroll correctly.

I added the logic as follows to allow the bounds to be correctly calculated before scrolling to range.

```
BOOL autoscroll = NO;

//I added a 10 px buffer here to allow for better detection as the textview is auto populated 
if (textView.contentOffset.y >= (textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height - 10))
{
    autoscroll = YES;
}

[textView setText:messageString];
[textView layoutSubviews];

if(autoscroll) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),     dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 1)];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (_moveToBottom) {
        int y = textView.contentSize.height - textView.frameHeight + self.textView.contentInset.bottom + self.textView.contentInset.top;
        if(y > 0) {
            [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];
        }
        _moveToBottom = NO;
    }
    else {
        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length]-1, 1)];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"] && range.location == [textView.text length]) {
        _moveToBottom = YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentOffset`, it will automatically scroll to down

```
textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height);
```