# UITextView scroll

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

This is a real n00b question but i am very new at this and have been looking for an answer and also read the reference as i am trying to work with UITextView.

I want to add quite a lot of text into a view and i want it to be scrollable.

I have created the UITextView in IB, added text via "self.myTextView.text = @"...", which works. However i am not able to scroll down and see all text. I see only the amount of text that fits in the view i have.

I wonder if someone nice could help me and give an example/hint how to get the UITextView scrollable.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528277/uitextview-automatic-scroll-down

Comment: A BIG thank you Orbit :-) It was the 'User Interaction Enabled' i had to re-enable, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's static text and you'd like some formatting, I recommend using a UIWebView. You can give it a variety of files types, and edit the file easily.