# UITextView cursor not positioning properly when editing in iOS 7. Why?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7, uitextview

[image: Why is this a thing thats happening]

That yellow box above is an editable UITextView that is currently being edited (is first responder). But you probably couldn't tell right? Because there is no cursor. But there is... It's that small blue dot in the bottom left of the yellow textView. It's slightly below the textViews bottom border. So if I keep going to a new line, or pressing enter, the text will move up as it naturally should. But the cursor is never "level", or right above the UITextView's bottom border. It's always just barely poking out of the bottom, a couple points below the border.

Why? This wasn't a problem in iOS 6. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I faced the same situation and I made that uitextview as scrollable, it started working for me. Its kinda weird but worked for me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

this bug is in iOS 7.0 you can solve this by modifying textView delegate method.

**try below code**

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect line = [textView caretRectForPosition:
        textView.selectedTextRange.start];
    CGFloat overflow = line.origin.y + line.size.height
        - ( textView.contentOffset.y + textView.bounds.size.height
        - textView.contentInset.bottom - textView.contentInset.top );
    if ( overflow > 0 ) {
    // We are at the bottom of the visible text and introduced a line feed, scroll down (iOS 7 does not do it)
    // Scroll caret to visible area
        CGPoint offset = textView.contentOffset;
        offset.y += overflow + 7; // leave 7 pixels margin
    // Cannot animate with setContentOffset:animated: or caret will not appear
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            [textView setContentOffset:offset];
        }];
    }
}
```

your problem will solved.

Comment: this is correct in setting the cursor to be on end of the text view but there's a problem here when you input characters.. it went up higher as you type and go below when you stop. It seems to be irritating to the eyes.. any fix?

Comment: it is working fine for me I didn't face problem like you told.

Comment: This is great. Another issue is when your first selected text portion is at the end of the screen, thus covered by the upcoming keyboard. I had to add this code to textViewDidChangeSelection as well to cover that situation

Comment: Just a note on this solution: I've found that this only works when you're typing above the frame's bottom. If you're typing at the bottom of the textView's contentOffset (assuming you have assigned a value to the contentOffset's bottom value) this does not work all the time.

Comment: Do somebody know if this bug already in rdar or any signs from Apple side that it will be fixed ?

Comment: @chibimai I had the same problem because I had a status bar/nav bar. I subtracted the status/nav height from the overflow before the `if overflow > 0` line.

Comment: Pratik's answer crashes at CGRect line = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start] where line.origin.y is returned as inf.
Anyone has a fix for this crash issue?

Comment: @Any one: why do we need 7 pixels margin? is it determined?

Comment: @Shilpi is exactly correct, this code **will crash** in some cases. I haven't debugged it enough yet though. It's probably sufficient to make the if statement be `if (overflow > 0 && !isnan(line.origin.y) && !isinf(line.origin.y))` until this is debugged further, that should at least prevent a crash inside of the text view's `setContentOffset:`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a navigation controller scenario, I think this is actually a result of a property that was introduced in iOS 7: `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` (see [iOS 7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1))

This defaults to YES, and will try to get clever with the UITextView (which is itself a scroll view) by adjusting the scroll offset for the height of the navigation controller.

The solution is therefore to set this property to NO in your `viewDidLoad` (being careful not to call it on iOS 6 since it's only available as of iOS 7).

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer that Todd gave, you could put something like this in a method that runs when the application finishes launching:

```
   [[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This will affect all the UITextFields and UITextViews.

Comment: What does changing the tint color have to do with the cursor placement?

Comment: I got here in search fro a solution for my invisible cursor and I found that Todd's answer fixed my issue. I added this answer as an improvement to Todd's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)sender shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSString * newText = [sender.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    [self setFramesForText:newText];

    if (!IOS_VERSION_6_OR_LESS) {
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
            [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(textView.contentOffset.x, 999999999)];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You just need to set the tintColor of the UITextView.

Put something like the following in the code (I put it in the viewDidLoad) worked for me.

```
self.textView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Best solution to this so far.

Comment: This changes the color of the cursor...How does this solve the problem?

Comment: I'm so desperate for fixes related to UITextView in iOS 7 that I actually tried this solution. Red didn't work, but orange did.